# Upload/Submit Images to twitter/MySpace from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, twitter, myspace

I have to upload an image from iphone app to twitter and myspace. I tried but didn't find any solution. Any one can help. Specially if anyone can indicate the sample code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you even try to use search? A search on SO or Google would have revealed at least 20 good code samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use http://dev.twitpic.com/

Post your image in http request here.

Here is the code -

```
-(void)postToTwitter
{

// create the URL
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitpic.com/1/uploadAndPost.xml"];

// create the connection
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:30.0];

// change type to POST (default is GET)
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



// create data
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *username = emailTextField.text;
NSString *password = passTextField.text;

NSString *consumer_token=@"consumer token";
NSString *consumer_secret=@"consumer secret ";
NSString *oauth_token=@"oauth token";
NSString *oauth_secret=@"oauth secret";
NSString *api_key=@"api key";

NSString *message = commentTxt.text;


// just some random text that will never occur in the body
NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
// header value
NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
// set header
[postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// username part
 [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postBody appendData:[username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 // password part
 [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postBody appendData:[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// api_key
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[api_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// consumer_token
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"consumer_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[consumer_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// consumer_secret
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"consumer_secret\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[consumer_secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//oauth_token
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[oauth_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//oauth_secret
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_secret\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[oauth_secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// message part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// media part
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"fish.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

img=[cFun correctImageOrientation:img];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);

// add it to body
[postBody appendData:imageData];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// final boundary
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// add body to post
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

// pointers to some necessary objects
//NSURLResponse* response;
//NSError* error;
[activity_bg setHidden:NO];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}

}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: @Mas: Did this answer help you out?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, I already have consumer key and secret, Now I applied for oauth token and secret. Any Help in the MySpace?

Comment: You are always welcome. I will post soon for MySpace as well. Glad that I helped you. :)

Comment: @ParthBhatt can you provide an example

Answer (score 2):

You can't upload images directly to twitter. You need to use an image service such at twitpic, which will have it's own api - http://twitpic.com/api.do  (there are many alternatives eg yfrog).

You could UIImagePickerController to get an image, and then just write some code to post to your chosen image service.