# upload image to twitter by using "http://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Anyone could you guide me or produce some source code using this api "http://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json". This is a twitter api for uploading image from iphone application to twitter in direct way.

Here my code.

```
enter code here

-(void)PostToTwitter
{
    NSString *consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;

    NSString *consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

    NSString *accessTokenKey = kOAuthaccessTokenKey;

    NSString *secretTokenKey = kOAuthsecretTokenKey;

    NSString *url = @"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json";

    OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:consumerKey secret:consumerSecret];



    OAToken *authToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithKey:accessTokenKey secret:secretTokenKey];

    OAMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] consumer:consumer token:authToken realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];

    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [postRequest prepare]; 


    NSString *message = @"Testing Tweet and image upload to Twitter server directly.";



    //NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    NSString *stringBoundary = @"----------------------------9fa90e137c50";

    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

    [postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];



    // message part

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"; filename=\"sunflower.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

    UIImage  *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sunflower.jpg"] ;//=[self correctImageOrientation:img];   //cFun
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);

    /*NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.prepare-community.com/ShareFiles/index-fr.jpg"];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];*/

   // NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"road.jpg"]);

    [postBody appendData:imageData];

    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];



    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];



    if (theConnection)
    {

        webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"web data = %@ =",webData);

    }

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    //[responseData appendData:data];
    [webData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //[connection release];

    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"result: %@", responseString);

    // [responseString release];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error - read error object for details");
}
```

In this above code, i got the output of WebData is <> empty tag.

And the responstring is {"errors":[{"message":"Internal error","code":131}]}

could please tell me why i get this error. where i was wrong in my above code. if anybody know solution for uploading image to twitter by using udate_with_media method, please guide me or post some source code.

Comment: **Check below links. might help**


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584820/upload-submit-images-to-twitter-myspace-from-iphone


https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine


**This one has demo too**
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/posting-images-using-twrequest

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for post in Twitter.

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

    SLComposeViewController *twitterComposer = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    //add initial text
    [twitterComposer setInitialText:@"Tweeting from iPhone 5 #TesingApp"];

    //present composer
    [self presentViewController:twitterComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"twitter Error"
                              message:@"You may not have set up twitter service on your device or\n                                  You may not connected to internent.\nPlease check ..."
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

This will only use in iOS 6+.

Comment: thanks for reply. but my deployment target is 3.0, so i don't want to use twitter and account frame work.if you know any changes my above code i will accept it jay.

Comment: The version 1 of the Twitter API is deprecated; there is no easy way to do what you're trying to accomplish without a significant amount of work. Take a look at [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) for an example of how to integrate older apps with Twitter.

Comment: @Ash Furrow i almost done send text to twitter by using MGTwitterEngine. Now i try to post image to twitter. please see this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614829/upload-image-to-twitter-in-iphone" and give me guide to me. please help