# upload image to twitter in iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter

how to upload image to twitter by using this method

```
- (NSString *) _uploadImage:(UIImage *)image requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)requestType responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)responseType
```

i get this method from stackoverflow.com that's the link is here,

[Twitter's statuses/update_with_media on iOS returns 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316776/twitters-statuses-update-with-media-on-ios-returns-500-error).

in the above link, it's work for great said 4 members, they are Ahmed, olivarseF, Gypsa and another one is Tk189.

here the code is below,

enter code here

```
- (NSString *) _uploadImage:(UIImage *)image requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)requestType responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)responseType
{

        NSString *boundary = @"----------------------------991990ee82f7";

        NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];
        if (!finalURL) 
        {
            return nil;
        }

        NSLog(@"-> Open Connection: %@", finalURL);


        OAMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:finalURL
                                                                          consumer:self.consumer
                                                                             token:_accessToken 
                                                                             realm: nil
                                                                 signatureProvider:nil];

        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

        // Set headers for client information, for tracking purposes at Twitter.
        [theRequest setValue:_clientName    forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client"];
        [theRequest setValue:_clientVersion forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-Version"];
        [theRequest setValue:_clientURL     forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-URL"];


        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [theRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:0];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media_data[]\"; filename=\"1.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Honeymoon uploads image\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // modificaiton from the base clase
        // our version "prepares" the oauth url request
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [theRequest prepare];

        [theRequest setHTTPBody:body];

        // Create a connection using this request, with the default timeout and caching policy, 
        // and appropriate Twitter request and response types for parsing and error reporting.
        MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection *connection;
        connection = [[MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest 
                                                                delegate:self 
                                                             requestType:requestType 
                                                            responseType:responseType];

        if (!connection) 
        {
            return nil;
        } 
        else 
        {
            [_connections setObject:connection forKey:[connection identifier]];
            //[connection release];
        }

        return [connection identifier];  
    }
```

In the above code it was integrated in SA_OAuthtwitterengine class and this line,

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

gave me the error report so i import NSData+Base64 file the error was clear.

then i try to send image using this line [_engine sendupdate:@"http://www.xxxx.com/ccc.jpg"];

here i want sent image as a url, but here i got this error **" Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"**

why? how to send this one please if u know this answer and especially i request you to mr.(ahmed, oliversf, gypsa and tk189) please explain how you use in saouthtwitter engine class.

Comment: @bhuXan could you know solution for above issue. please help me it's very urgent.

Comment: anybody here please help me it's very urgent

Comment: raman: u checked this pal, https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/15177

Comment: and if your app is for iOS5 n later then below answer could serve ur purpose..

Comment: @bhuXan ya i use the same code in SA_OuthTwitterengine class. my doubt is how to upload image? for eg, if u post text to twitter in oauth, we use [_engine sendupdate:@"hello twitter"] it will successfully send to twitter. but here i want send image as URL format. i use [_engine sendupdate:@"https://xxx.com/share/road.jpg"] i got the 401 error. i was confused.

Comment: try without UIImageJPEGRepresentation conversion..

Comment: @bhuXan i got same error,cause #define SET_AUTHORIZATION_IN_HEADER 1

- (NSString *)_sendRequestWithMethod:(NSString *)method 
                                path:(NSString *)path 
                     queryParameters:(NSDictionary *)params 
                                body:(NSString *)body 
                         requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)requestType 
                        responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)responseType

Comment: sendupdate method only accept text post not image post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a particular framework?
If your application support app support >= iOS 5 you can use Social framework already integrated in the iOS SDK with something like this:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    NSString *title = [self.elementInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"message you want to display"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: my application support from minimum deployment target is 3.0(ios,ipod). so i used MGTwitterengine,SA_OAuthtwitterengine and OAuthconsumer classes. And i successfully done post text to twitter account. but past two months i try to image post on twitter. i doesn't got clear solution.